# Matlab blakechart discrepancy

Tags: matlab

The Phased Array System Toolbox from matlab provides the function [**`blakechart`**](https://mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/blakechart.html). If you type `help blakechart` in the matlab command window the following example code is provided.

```
% Example:
%   Plot the radar vertical coverage pattern assuming the antenna has a
%   sinc pattern. The frequency is 100 MHz, the antenna height is 20
%   feet, and the range is 100 nautical miles. Assume the surface is
%   smooth, the antenna is not tilted and in horizontal polarization.

pat_angles = linspace(-90,90,361)';
pat_u = 1.39157/sind(90/2)*sind(pat_angles);
pat = sinc(pat_u/pi);

freq = 100e6;     % MHz
ant_height = 20;  % ft
rng_fs = 100;     % Nautical mile
tilt_ang = 0;     % degrees
[vcd, vcd_ang] = radarvcd(freq,rng_fs,ant_height,...
    'RangeUnit','nmi','HeightUnit','ft','AntennaPattern',pat,...
    'PatternAngles',pat_angles,'TiltAngle',tilt_ang);

blakechart(vcd, vcd_ang, 200, 600e3, 'RangeUnit','nmi',...
    'HeightUnit','ft')
```

Running this code produces the following plot 
[image: blakechart from matlab].

However, the matlab code is based on the paper [Machine Plotting of Radio/Radar Vertical-Plane Coverage Diagram](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/709897.pdf). More importantly, Figure 6 in that paper is the matlab example provided above. I've attached Figure 6 from that paper

[image: here].

Notice that the plots don't agree? Look at the places I've circled in the two figures I've uploaded.

Comment: What is the answer you are looking for? Is the data the same? Is the function supposed to be doing the same? Are you worried MATLAB being wrong? The paper?

Comment: I'm hoping to find out if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is a bug in matlab. Yes the data/parameters are the same and the function should be doing the same. Thanks!

Comment: There is a very different scaling going on in both plots. HAve you considered that perhaps the one in the paper doest get exactly to 60000, you just don't see it?

Comment: If you output the matlab values from `[vcd, vcd_ang]` you can see that at 60 degrees the range is 113 nmi. And by looking at the first figure you can also see that at 60 degrees the height is about 600000 ft. If you then look at the second figure you see that at 60 degrees the height is well below  600000 ft and the range is about 100 nmi. Thanks for your help!